# how to make multiple row from a column which is having 5 value separated with comma?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, numpy

my input is

```
category      destination          type        value
voice         USA, Canada, India   individual    5
Voice         USA, Canada, India   individual    7
```

output should be

```
category      destination          type        value
voice         USA                  individual    5
Voice         Canada               individual    5
Voice         India                individual    5
Voice         USA                  individual    7
Voice         Canada               individual    7
Voice         India                individual    7
```

i tried with explode function but its not working.

Comment: Format your data to make this readable (ie, using the | between columns to make this display as a table). Also show your coded attempt where you tried using the explode function. Explode works well for Array column type.

Comment: You had [tag:sql], [tag:pandas], and [tag:numpy], but I don't see any code that includes these packages. In fact, I don't see any code at all...